# How can I convert JSON file into List of objects?

Tags: java, json, list, object

I'm trying to do a loader for my program and the saver into json works, but the reader doesn't. I'm basically converting my list of objects, let's say ArrayList ProjectArr into json which is working, now I'm gonna close terminal and load the info into my initially blank ProjectArr list so I can add the saved data loading feature. here is my reader :

```
public static ArrayList<Project> MapReaderforProject() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapperforProject = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonfile = "C:/Users/elmm/Desktop/DS Project/DsProject/target/test1.json";
    File file = new File("C:/Users/elmm/Desktop/DS Project/DsProject/target/test1.json");
    try {
        ProjectArr = objectMapperforProject.readValue(jsonfile,new TypeReference<ArrayList<Project>>(){});
    }
    catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    }
    System.out.println(ProjectArr.toString());
    return ProjectArr;
}
```

But when I call this even though the JSON file is working and has the info, it's not reading anything and just prints [], empty list basically meaning it's not reading the data from JSON back into my list. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

There is some context information missing to give you more help. For example, what is `ObjectMapper`? Does it come from a library (and from which one) or have you written it yourself?

But what I have recognized so far: In line 3 you create a `String` which contains the file name. In line 4 you create a `File` object with the same file name. You could use the `String` there which you created the line above.

In line 6 you call the `readValue` method on the `ObjectMapper` instance and pass the `String` created in line 3, which contains the file name. Does this method really want a `String` there with the file name? If this is the `ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library, you need to parse the JSON code as the first parameter to the `readValue` call, not the file name.

So it looks like after line 4 you need code to read the content of the file which you should pass to the `readValue` method.

Check out this short tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

hth
McPringle

Comment: It is from Jackson Library, not something I wrote from scratch. I have seen this tutorial, that's why I'm a bit confused, I have already done the same as it has, but to no avail. The reason I have both string of JSON path and also a file was because I thought maybe the issue is from there so I tried both.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I showed you? Were you successful?

Comment: I had previously read the baeldung tutorial. I did all according to that.

Comment: And have you tried the solution? In my answer, I gave you the solution to your problem!